# Write a program to find whether the given matrix is null or not using functions and double pointers?

Tags: c, matrix

In the following program the execution stops after the function call, Tell me why and how to solve this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int checkNull(int **a,int m,int n)
{
  int null=0,i,j;
  for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      if(a[i][j]==0)
         null++;
  return null;
}
int main()
{
  int a[10][10],null,i,j,m,n;
  printf("Enter the number of rows in the matrix");
  scanf("%d",&m);
  printf("\nEnter the number of columns in the matrix");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("\nEnter the elements in the matrix");
  for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    printf("\nThe matrix is");
  for(i=0;i<m;i++)
  {
    printf("\n");
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
  }
    null=checkNull((int **)a,m,n);
  if(null==m*n)
    printf("\nThe matrix is null");
  else
    printf("\nThe matrix is not null");  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to have the `checkNull()` function actually check for null.  I would change it to:

```
int checkNull(int a[][10],int m,int n)
{
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      if(a[i][j]!=0)
         return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

Then the call would look like:

```
  if(checkNull(a,m,n))
    printf("\nThe matrix is null");
  else
    printf("\nThe matrix is not null");
```

From the question however it looks like you want to use double pointers for this problem.  That would make sense if you created an array of pointers that point to each row, then allocate everything dynamically.  This also has the advantage that it will work for any size matrix.  Something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int checkNull(int **a, int m, int n)
{
  int *row, i, j;
  for(i=0; i<m; i++)
  {
    row = a[i];
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
      if(row[j] != 0)
        return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}

int main()
{
  int **a, i, j, m, n;
  printf("Enter the number of rows in the matrix");
  scanf("%d", &m);
  a = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * m);
  printf("\nEnter the number of columns in the matrix");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("\nEnter the elements in the matrix");
  for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
  {
    a[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
      scanf("%d", a[i] + j);
  }
  printf("\nThe matrix is");
  for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
  {
    printf("\n");
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
      printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
  }
  if(checkNull(a, m, n))
    printf("\nThe matrix is null");
  else
    printf("\nThe matrix is not null");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function call is wrong:

```
null=checkNull((int **)a,m,n);
```

Explicitly casting  `a` to `int**` is not right.

Given you definition of `a`, you need to change the function `checkNull` to:

```
int checkNull(int (*a)[10], int m, int n) { ... }
```

and call the function using

```
null=checkNull(a, m, n);
```

If you use:

```
int a[10][20];
```

then, you need to change `checkNull` to:

```
int checkNull(int (*a)[20], int m, int n) { ... }
```